Regex to extract WordPress wp-config database information and automating it with ansible to update a shared hosting environment
Dears,
I need your support with this below regex I've been at it for the last 5 hours and could not figure it out
define\(\s*[\'"]DB_HOST[\'"]\s*,\s*[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"]\)
The task I have is simple I need a regex to extract WordPress database information and I will be using it in an Ansible playbook
/\*\* The host of the database for WordPress \*/
define( 'DB_HOST', 'database_host_here' );

the above is the format
I tried more than regex with the help of ChatGPT and other GenAI tools but every output fails due to a regex escape issue
this is my current playbook
---
- name: Update wp-config.php with new template
  hosts: localhost

  vars_prompt:
    - name: username
      prompt: "Enter the username"
      private: false

  vars:
    wp_config_filename: "wp-config.php"
    enable_debug: false
    multi_site: false
    search_paths:
      - "/home/{{ username }}/public_html/public"

  tasks:
    - name: Find wp-config.php files
      ansible.builtin.find:
        paths: "{{ search_paths }}"
        patterns: "{{ wp_config_filename }}"
      register: wp_config_files

    - name: Fail if no wp-config.php files found
      ansible.builtin.fail:
        msg: "No wp-config.php files found in the provided paths."
      when: wp_config_files.matched == 0

    - name: Debug wp-config.php files
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: wp_config_files

    - name: Read existing wp-config.php for database credentials
      ansible.builtin.slurp:
        src: "{{ item.path }}"
      loop: "{{ wp_config_files.files }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item
      register: wp_config_content
      when: wp_config_files.matched > 0

    - name: Decode base64 encoded wp-config.php content
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        wp_config_decoded: "{{ wp_config_content.results | map(attribute='content') | map('b64decode') | list }}"

    - name: Debug decoded wp-config.php content
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: wp_config_decoded

    - name: Set database credentials from existing wp-config.php
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        db_host: "{{ item | regex_search('define\\(\\s*[\'\"]DB_HOST[\'\"]\\s*,\\s*[\'\"]([^\'\"]+)[\'\"]') | default('localhost') }}"
        db_name: "{{ item | regex_search('define\\(\\s*[\'\"]DB_NAME[\'\"]\\s*,\\s*[\'\"]([^\'\"]+)[\'\"]') | default('wordpress') }}"
        db_user: "{{ item | regex_search('define\\(\\s*[\'\"]DB_USER[\'\"]\\s*,\\s*[\'\"]([^\'\"]+)[\'\"]') | default('root') }}"
        db_password: "{{ item | regex_search('define\\(\\s*[\'\"]DB_PASSWORD[\'\"]\\s*,\\s*[\'\"]([^\'\"]+)[\'\"]') | default('password') }}"
      loop: "{{ wp_config_decoded }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item

    - name: Debug extracted database credentials
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: >
          DB Name: {{ db_name }},
          DB User: {{ db_user }},
          DB Password: {{ db_password }},
          DB Host: {{ db_host }}

    - name: Create a new wp-config.php from template
      ansible.builtin.template:
        src: "wp-config.php.j2"
        dest: "{{ item.path }}"
        mode: "0644"
      loop: "{{ wp_config_files.files }}"
      when: wp_config_files.matched > 0

I have a shared hosting environment with more than one WordPress website and I want to make all the settings are the same so I want to automate the detection of the database information, update the template, and place it in the correct path.
define\(\s*[\'"]DB_HOST[\'"]\s*,\s*[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"]\)

It fails with ansible
UPDATE
Thanks to @WiktorStribiżew I was able to figure out the solution to my issue
The new and updated regex value with regex_search for ansible
regex_search('define\\s*\\(\\s*[\\x22\\x27]DB_HOST[\\x22\\x27]\\s*,\\s*[\\x22\\x27]([^\\x22\\x27]+)[\\x22\\x27]\\s*\\)', '\\1') | first

UPDATE 2:
Based on @U880D's answer, if someone faces the same case or wants to implement the same task.
Full Playbook:
---
- name: Update wp-config.php with new template
  hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: Find all user directories under /home
      ansible.builtin.find:
        paths: "{{ search_path }}"
        file_type: directory
      register: user_dirs

    - name: Find all wp-config.php files in user directories
      ansible.builtin.find:
        paths: "{{ item.path }}/public_html"
        patterns: "wp-config.php"
      register: wp_config_files
      loop: "{{ user_dirs.files }}"

    - name: Fail if no wp-config.php files found
      ansible.builtin.fail:
        msg: "No wp-config.php files found in the provided paths."
      when: wp_config_files.matched == 0

    - name: Debug wp-config.php files
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: wp_config_files

    - name: Read existing wp-config.php for database credentials
      ansible.builtin.slurp:
        src: "{{ item.path }}"
      loop: "{{ wp_config_files.files }}"
      register: wp_config_content
      when: wp_config_files.matched > 0

    - name: Debug wp-config.php content
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: wp_config_content.results

    - name: Set database credentials from existing wp-config.php
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        db_host: >-
          {{ item.content | b64decode | regex_search('DB_HOST(.+)', '\\1') | regex_search('([A-Za-z])+') }}
        db_name: >-
          {{ item.content | b64decode | regex_search('DB_NAME(.+)', '\\1') | regex_search('([A-Za-z])+') }}
        db_user: >-
          {{ item.content | b64decode | regex_search('DB_USER(.+)', '\\1') | regex_search('([A-Za-z])+') }}
        db_password: >-
          {{ item.content | b64decode | regex_search('DB_PASSWORD(.+)', '\\1') | regex_search('([A-Za-z])+') }}
      loop: "{{ wp_config_content.results }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item
      when: item.content is defined

    - name: Debug extracted database credentials
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: >-
          DB Name: {{ db_name }},
          DB User: {{ db_user }},
          DB Password: {{ db_password }},
          DB Host: {{ db_host }}

    - name: Create a new wp-config.php from template
      ansible.builtin.template:
        src: "wp-config.php.j2"
        dest: "{{ item.path }}"
        mode: "0644"
      loop: "{{ wp_config_files.files }}"
      when: wp_config_files.matched > 0


Regex has DB_HOST but string has DB_NAME.

After the update your value has trailing whitespace but your regex does not. You need \s* before closing ). e.g. define\(\s*[\'"]DB_HOST[\'"]\s*,\s*[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"]\s*\)

Thank you for this, I am trying to add escape to it to use in Ansible Yaml file
- name: Set database credentials from existing wp-config.php       ansible.builtin.set_fact:         db_host: "{{ item | regex_search('define\\(\\s*[\"\\\']DB_HOST[\"\\\']\\s*,\\s*[\"\\\']([^\"\\\']+)[\"\\\']\\s*\\)') | default('localhost') }}"       loop: "{{ wp_config_decoded }}"       loop_control:         loop_var: item
I keep getting this error:
Syntax Error while loading YAML.
found unknown escape character
Any feedback?

You may use entities instead of literal quotes: define\\(\\s*[\\x22\\x27]DB_HOST[\\x22\\x27]\\s*,\\s*[\\x22\\x27]([^\\x22\\x27]+)[\\x22\\x27]\\s*\\). Add '\\1' as the second argument to regex_search if you need the Group 1 value.

@WiktorStribiżew Thank you so so much it worked. ❤️

@WiktorStribiżew could you assist me with one more thing I am getting values like this ['wordpress'] but I want them like this WordPress

@WiktorStribiżew even though I am using "\1"
 - name: Set database credentials from existing wp-config.php       ansible.builtin.set_fact:         db_host: "{{ item.content | b64decode | regex_search('define\\(\\s*[\\x22\\x27]DB_HOST[\\x22\\x27]\\s*,\\s*[\\x22\\x27]([^\\x22\\x27]+)[\\x22\\x27]\\s*\\)', '\\1') }}"       loop: "{{ wp_config_content.results }}"       loop_control:         loop_var: item       when: item.content is defined

@WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much I was able to figure it out.

You also could group the quote type, then use a back reference for the matching of it. Should simplify regex a bit, and make it more accurate. ([\\x22\\x27])DB_HOST\\1.. roughly, untested but that should be it. Will need to adjust backreference number by where it is used in regex.

There is a workaround for adding double and single quotes to your regex pattern if you have trouble understanding how to escape them inside your string literals. This works with most -if not all - NFA regex engines.
You can match " with \x22 and ' with \x27 escape entity.
So, your pattern will look like
regex_search('define\\(\\s*[\\x22\\x27]DB_HOST[\\x22\\x27]\\s*,\\s*[\\x22\\x27]([^\\x22\\x27]+)[\\x22\\x27]\\s*\\)')

Note that if you need to get the group value from the result, you need to specify it as the second argument to regex_search:
regex_search('define\\(\\s*[\\x22\\x27]DB_HOST[\\x22\\x27]\\s*,\\s*[\\x22\\x27]([^\\x22\\x27]+)[\\x22\\x27]\\s*\\)', '\\1')

Since you obtain a list as a result of your code execution, and you only need the first item in that list, all you need is to add the  | first after your regex search command.

Maybe a simpler approach is feasible like shown in the minimal example
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    wp_config_decoded: |
      define( 'DB_NAME', 'test' );
      /\*\* The host of the database for WordPress \*/
      define( 'DB_HOST', 'database_host_here' );

  tasks:

    - name: Given answer
      debug:
        msg: "{{ wp_config_decoded | regex_search('define\\(\\s*[\\x22\\x27]DB_HOST[\\x22\\x27]\\s*,\\s*[\\x22\\x27]([^\\x22\\x27]+)[\\x22\\x27]\\s*\\)', '\\1') | first }}"

    - name: Easier to read, maintain and operate
      debug:
        msg: "{{ wp_config_decoded | regex_search('DB_NAME(.+)', '\\1') | regex_search('([A-Za-z])+') }}"

resulting into an output of
TASK [Given answer] ***************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: database_host_here

TASK [Easier to read, maintain and operate] ***
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: test

Thanks To

Extracting part of the string using Ansible regex_search and save the output as a variable


This works also and it is a simpler solution, thank you.
